# Proof in Higher Algebra that $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$ is presentable

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, infinity-categories, higher-algebra, locally-presentable-categories

In Higher Algebra Lemma 4.8.4.2, Lurie shows that for $\mathcal{K}$ a small set of simplicial sets, the $\infty$-category $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$ of small $\infty$-categories with $K$-shaped colimits and functors preserving $K$-shaped colimits for all $K \in \mathcal{K}$, is presentable (and the tensor product on this category preserves colimits in both variables).

I am confused about the part of the proof that verifies accessibility. At the beginning of this part, Lurie fixes a "large enough" cardinal $\tau$ and denotes by $\mathcal{C}at^\tau(\mathcal{K})$ the full subcategory of $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$ on $\tau$-small categories. He says:

> Then $\mathcal{C}at^\tau(\mathcal{K})$ is an essentially small category; it will therefore suffice to prove that every object $\mathcal{C} \in \mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$ is the colimit (in $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$) of a diagram taking values in $\mathcal{C}at^\tau (\mathcal{K})$.

This is the part that puzzles me: Why does this suffice? Don't we also need to know that every object of $\mathcal{C}at^\tau(\mathcal{K})$ is $\mu$-compact in $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$, for some fixed cardinal $\mu$? I don't think this is clear.

Comment: I guess that $\tau$-small categories are $\tau$-compact. If I understand correctly, the proof of [HTT, Prop 5.5.7.11] implies that the functor $\operatorname{Cat}(\mathcal K)\to\operatorname{Cat}$ preserves $\tau$-filtered colimits, thus it suffices to see the $\tau$-compactness of $\tau$-small categories in $\operatorname{Cat}$, which seems to follow from the fact that $\operatorname{Cat}$ is compactly generated by $\ast$ and $\Delta^1$.

Comment: @ Z. M Thanks for the reference! That should solve my question; I'll write it out in an answer.

Comment: While writing out the proof, there was another problem: If $\mathcal{C} \in \mathcal{C}at^\tau(\mathcal{K})$ is $\tau$-compact in $\mathcal{C}at$ (by HTT 5.4.1.2 this is equiv. to $\tau$-small), then $\operatorname{Fun}(\mathcal{C}, -)^\simeq$ commutes with $\tau$-filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}at$, so by your statement in particular also in $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$. But we want to show that taking $\mathcal{K}$-colimit-preserving functors $\operatorname{Fun}^{\mathcal{K}}(\mathcal{C}, -)^\simeq$ commutes with $\tau$-filtered colimits.

Comment: In other words this shows that the left adjoint $\mathcal{P}^{\mathcal{K}}: \mathcal{C}at \to \mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$ preserves $\tau$-compact objects, but unlike I thought/ wrote [I edited this out] this is not precisely the statement we need.

Comment: I think I was able to fix it, hopefully the proof below is correct (and not too overly cumbersome)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that by HTT 5.4.1.2 since $\tau$ is an *uncountable* regular cardinal, an $\infty$-category is $\tau$-compact iff it is $\tau$-small. Our first step is to show that the inclusion $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K}) \to \mathcal{C}at$ preserves $\tau$-filtered colimits.

As pointed out by Z. M in the comments, this follows using the same argument in the proof of HTT 5.5.7.11, which shows that the inclusion $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K}_{\tau\mathrm{-small}}) \to \mathcal{C}at$ preserves $\tau$-filtered colimits, for $\mathcal{K}_{\tau\mathrm{-small}}$ the collection of all $\tau$-small simplicial sets. By our choice of $\tau$, we have $\mathcal{K} \subseteq \mathcal{K}_{\tau\mathrm{-small}}$ so that we can just always restrict $K$ to lie in this subset and the proof works verbatim.

Now, if $\mathcal{C} \in \mathcal{C}at^\tau (\mathcal{K})$ it is in particular $\tau$-compact in $\mathcal{C}at$, so the functor $\operatorname{Map}_{\mathcal{C}at} (\mathcal{C}, -)$ commutes with $\tau$-filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}at$. By the above argument, it also commutes with $\tau$-filtered colimits in $\mathcal{C}at (\mathcal{K})$ as they are computed in the same manner.

We however would like to show that the subfunctor $\operatorname{Map}_{\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})} (\mathcal{C}, -)$ on those functors that preserve $\mathcal{K}$-colimits commutes with $\tau$-filtered colimits. In other words, for $(\mathcal{D}_i)$ a $\tau$-filtered diagram in $\mathcal{C}at(\mathcal{K})$ with colimit $\mathcal{D}$, a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}$ should preserve $\mathcal{K}$-colimits iff (note $\mathcal{C}$ is $\tau$-compact in $\mathcal{C}at$) it comes from a functor $\mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{D}_i$ for some $i$ that preserves $\mathcal{K}$-colimits. This again follows from the proof of HTT 5.5.7.11.